# Python Telegram Bot set long list of commands

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'd like to add a long list of commands to my **Telegram Bot**, however in **BotFather** I can only send a list of commands and descriptions in a text with up to 4,000 characters. If I send the remainder of the commands via another text, the previous list of commands gets deleted, since BotFather thinks this is the "new" list.

Is there a way to set up commands with descriptions directly in my **Python** script, so that these can be visible to users when typing the /commands in the chat?

Otherwise, is it possible to set commands in bulk in BotFather without using the chat?

Answer (score 1):

Commands lists are limited by design, the point is not to provide a list of every command your bot is capable of handling, but only suggesting the most usual ones.

> Is there a way to set up commands with descriptions directly in my Python script, so that these can be visible to users when typing the /commands in the chat?

You can automate your own account to send messages and commands to `BotFather` and thus automate changing your bot's commands list. [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon), for instance, allows you to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining. Can you point me to the right documentation in Telethon where I can find some recommended scripts to use to send messages and commands to BotFather?

Comment: You'll find everything you need here https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/

Comment: I managed to do it, although I can only send up to 4,096 characters unfortunately. Thanks a lot anyway, really helpful! Do you know if there is a script that I can use to show some suggestions/descriptions when an user starts typing a text in a chat? Something very similar to the /commands function, where you get that small pop up above the message box when you start typing a command.

Comment: Closest thing to this are [inline queries](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline), but these are pretty different (used to provide functionality in other chats) and probably not suited to your use case